# .live() does not behave like .bind()

Tags: javascript, jquery

After asking this question : [jQuery die() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037511/jquery-die-does-not-work). I found that `live()` does not seem to behave like `bind()`.

I had the following line:

```
$('.produit').die().live('change',function(){ // the rest
$('.produit').live('change',function(){ // that did not work either
```

Then I changed it to:

```
$('.produit').unbind('change').bind('change',function(){ // the rest
```

What is the difference between the two lines.

In this example `.produit` is added dynamically to the page. And the binding is done after the `prepend()`.

I'm using jQuery 1.4.2, and IE7.

Comment: p.s. you should *really* consider upgrading jQuery if at all possible. You'll find it is very good at backwards compatibility. [1.4.2 is olddddd](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use IE there is some problem with live and `change` event

search for `livequery` plugin which solves this.

try to change the event to `Click` event and youll see that it works.

The difference is that Bind is for Already In Page elements and live is also+Future elements.

Comment: This one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637503/jquery-change-event-on-select-not-firing-in-ie

Comment: there is no unbind for Live - its Unbind is Die.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That was probably in an older version of jQuery. The latest versions cover up IE's shortcomings seamlessly.

Comment: @Matt I know but hes using old ver. ( I had this problem on 1.3.2) I dont know if it fixed on 1.4

Comment: This is a very vague answer. It would be better to explain that the `change` event doesn't bubble in IE so `live`, which binds to a parent element and then triggers the event with the proper context, never receives word that the `change` event occurred. If `livequery` solves this, an example and/or link would be a great way to really hit it home.

Comment: @Royi So the `change` event presumably doesn't bubble up the DOM tree in IE... As a result, event delegation (which `live` is) won't work.

Comment: @coreyward `live` binds at the `document` object, not the parent element.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas if you want to bind direct to the parent you should use delegate

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Yes, and it is the parent of everything on the page. Point is the bubbling has to occur or it won't be notified. `.live` is also deprecated and David should be using `.delegate` instead.

Comment: @coreyward `document` is the *ancestor* of every element, not the parent.

Comment: @coreyward Actually, jQuery is pushing `.on()` and `.off()` since version 1.7, so `.delegate()` is kind-of deprecated, too.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas True, but he's using 1.4, not 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

Live does **not** behave like bind. That is correct.

Live attaches a handler for only predefined actions (like click or keypress). With bind you can define your own events and trigger them however you deem necessary.

All in all, in the end, it is better to use `bind` over `live`.  That is why in the newest jQuery 1.7 (which you are **not** using) there is the functions `on` and `off` which basically combines the functionality of `live`, `bind`, and `delagate`